# Counting number of GC cleanups on an object

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

How do I keep a count of the number of times that objects of a specific class (type?) are getting disposed in the lifetime of my application. Imagine I have a class A, now, I want to count how many times the objects of A get collected by the GC.

I hope I am phrasing this right because I was asked this in an interview today and the answer I gave did not satisfy the interviewer. And this is what I imagine he was trying to ask.

What I said was that one could keep a static field called *count* in the class A and increment it in the **Finalize()** call of that object.

The answer he was expecting was something called a static block. I've never heard of this in .NET/C#. Can someone explain what's this static block?

Comment: how i hate these questions.... your answer is correct because it will work. asker wants not correct answer but wants to hear what he thinks about. this is so stupid, i think.

Comment: To my knowledge, there is no such things as a `static block` in C# or .NET. Your answer of using a static variable with a finalizer is appropriate. A memory profiler would also work.

Comment: I shall give the memprofiler a try. Thanks for your answers guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a tool like [memprofiler](http://memprofiler.com/), [Redgate Ants](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_memory_profiler/index.htm), [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/index.html), [CLR Profiler](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=a362781c-3870-43be-8926-862b40aa0cd0&displaylang=en) (needs admin rights for .NET 3.5 [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055803/is-there-a-clr-profiler-that-works-with-net-3-5-sp1-and-wpf))  or the team edition of Visual Studio.

Comment: I'll be sure to check these out. Thanks Mitch.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe he was referring to a static constructor for the class?

```
public class Foo {

   public static Foo() { /* gets called once before first operator new */ }

}
```

Comment: @plinth, this is what I thought. But even at that, how can this help you keep track of how many times the class is disposed?

Comment: It doesn't.  That's the confusing part.

Comment: Yeah I think its a case of `that's the answer that's in the book`. Not quite sure what book they were reading...

Answer (score 0):

A static block is really another name for a [Static Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc(vs.71).aspx) in C#. It is called automatically to intialize a class before the first instance is created. I can't see how this will help you keep track of how many times a class is disposed though. Only way I could think of would be to have your class implement `IDisposable`, have a static field called `disposeCount` and increment it on every call to `Dispose` or to be sure as you rightly said in the `Finalize` method. Your answer was defintely not wrong, and you should point that out to them if you get a 2nd interview :)

Comment: Unfortunately, that was the final interview. I just told him I was not aware of something like that in .NET. I'll be more confident with my .NET skills next time. :)